# Is it possible to access website through IP address and path to index file?

Tags: networking, web, dns, ip

Is it possible to access website through IP address with path to index file instead of domain name?

**Example:**

- Domain: Youtube.com
- IP address: 216.58.209.142

Trying to access the website through IP address won't work. I understand this is because there can be multiple websites on the same IP address and the settings which directory gets sent to the user is set in nginx/apache.

Is it possible to visit the said website through for example `216.58.209.142/youtube/path/to/directory/index.html` ?

If this works then how would I be able to get the full URL path?

Just curious, I'm not trying to achieve anything particular.

Comment: What does this question have to do with application development? I think you are asking on the wrong SE site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's not possible.

Server can block your request even if you provide a correct/existing path, allowing you to access the data only using a correct domain name.

Comment: Finally found my answer. The website can be access via IP address if you add a Header Host with a domain name.  Example using wget:


```wget --header 'Host:example.com' http://93.184.216.34```

The point is not why would I do this. I needed to understand how it actually works and why wouldn't it allow.

Answer (score -2):

Just replace the www.youtube.com with YouTube's IP. For example: `216.58.209.142/index.html` (I don't know if YouTube has `index.html`, but if it did that's how you would access it)